# Convergent Evolution of Polycephalic (Multi-Headed) Organisms

Tags: creature-design, evolution, fauna, anatomy

In my fantasy story, various two- and three-headed creatures have evolved from past magical experiments.

For this question assume that:

- Although originally created in experiments, they can breed and **their offspring has multiple heads as well**.
- **Only creatures based on the same animal** (or animals that can mate normally)**, and with the same number of heads can breed** (two-headed wolves can't mate with three-headed wolves) However, a two-headed lion can mate with a two-headed tiger, giving birth to a two-headed [liger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liger).
- Enough time has passed where the evolution of these multi-headed species has **caused them to adapt to having multiple heads**. (ie they didn't all die off)

List of traits:

- Multiple heads
- Multiple hearts (one per head)
- One stomach
- Same number of legs as a normal one-headed specimen
- Heads are independent (ie they are separate 'minds')
- Control of limbs is shared (similar to video games or computers, when two people are trying to move the same cursor).

## What traits of these creatures would develop over time, as a byproduct of convergent evolution?

Being part of a whole, I assume they would evolve to work together. Possibly they would learn to always look in different directions, working together similarly to the eyes of a chameleon. I also imagine they would evolve longer necks to give each head more freedom of movement?

This question is concerned with the convergent evolution of all animals this might occur in (in my story it happened to almost every species).

---

However, if the above question is too broad:

## What traits of two- and three-headed quadrupedal mammals would develop over time, as a byproduct of convergent evolution?

---

And if even the above question is still too broad:

## What traits of *three-headed* predatory quadrupedal mammals (lion, wolf, etc.) would develop over time, as a byproduct of convergent evolution?

Comment: <sarcasm>Vote to close:too broad -- OP asking multiple questions in one post</sarcasm>

Comment: That aside... How is this not story-based? Supposing there was a separate personality for each head/brain, then wouldn't different specimens have different developing relationships between heads?

Comment: @Frostfyre Absolutely they would. But just like convergent evolution, I'm looking for the traits that tend to develop among all of them.

Comment: There seems to be a Monty Python solution to this question. "Get the sword out, I want to cut his head off!" "Oh cut your own head off!"

Comment: Asking for how an entirely hypothetical relationship would evolve seems like an entirely story-based question, so that's a VTC from me. Also, "_as the different heads struggle to gain full control of the body._" why would they? they've been like that from birth; they _have_ to be able to co-operate perfectly and fully if they expect to live a reasonable length of time. Squabbling three heads go hungry, fall over, get hurt, get infected and die.

Comment: @StarfishPrime I see your point. Maybe focusing on the relationships wasn't quite the right way to phrase it. I'm going to update the question and title appropriately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Disclaimer: this answer was written when the question focused on relationships, not evolution.**

There are a few potential answers.

First, if the heads can communicate telepathically(probably via a shared spinal cord, as that would allow them to share control over limbs), they would understand each other near-perfectly. This would most likely result in their acting like one individual animal.(but with multiple heads)

If the heads must communicate audibly, then there is a very similar situation. The animals where the separate personalities are significantly different will probably end up killing themselves or learning to get along, and if the personalities are similar they will get along to start with. When they get along, they will act much like the creatures in the telepathic situation, albeit with slower debates and response times.

In your interpretation, control over limbs is less complicated than it may seem. It is much like the video game *Trackmania: Turbo* in Double Driver mode. When playing in Double Driver mode, players’ actions are averaged out in order to control the car.(i.e. one player turns right, one player turns left, the car goes straight) While it is more difficult than single player, if both players are skilled, the car drives smoothly and there is not much communication beyond encouragement and simple commands. **I believe that these multi-headed creatures would live fairly normally, and act much like their single-headed counterparts and the heads would not struggle for control.** Not for long, at least :)

Comment: So, considering that these animals didn't die off, they almost certainly evolved in such a way where they would operate almost identically to the normal, single-headed variant?

Comment: @overlord Yes. The animals would most likely operate like the normal animals, but have more teeth, more eyes, and occasional disorientation/confusion(which is counterbalanced by the advantages).